# UnitTests that skip input Validation

Tags: spring-boot, rest, unit-testing, junit

I'm writing some tests for CRUD in my REST API.
The test went through fine until I implemented input validation.
It consists for the moment just of checking the validity of the password.

In my service, if the validation returns false, I throw w custom IncorrectPasswordStructureException.

I know how to assert correct and incorrect input, but how can I test without the validation?

Should I create a custom save() method in my Service, that does not validate, and use the one with validation for my API?
I'm new to UnitTesting, so I'm not sure.

Thanks for all the feedback.

Happy coding

Comment: Please add the relevant code parts for your existing setup.

Comment: Mocking is probably the answer to your problem, but please share code of method you want to test, it would help to provide concrete insights